# Override window drop in Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nswindowcontroller

I'm looking for a way to customize the drag/drop of windows/tabs. I have a document based app, with a custom window controller. I am able to create tabs for it and have them all along the top, they all show, everything works great with that.

Where I'm running into trouble is if I create a different unconnected windows and start trying to drag windows or tabs into different windows or tab bars to have it dock or merge. Sometimes it works how I want, sometimes it doesn't allow docking or anything. Other times it does what I don't want it to do. I need a way to help it along...

I'm looking for a way to tie into those events but in all my searching I can't find what api or where it is that is controlling the window drags/drops. I looked into the `NSDraggingDestination` but that has nothing relating to windows, just pasteboard stuff. Looked at `NSWindowController` and didn't see anything there either. Anyone know if this is possible?